# Opposite of "setting on fire"

Tags: phrase-request

What do firefighters do with buildings on fire? What is opposite of "setting on fire"? "putting fire down"?

Please give more than one suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefighters **put out** or **extinguish** a fire. You can also **knock down** a fire.

To *put down* a fire means to put it under control, not necessarily to put it out.

Comment: I've never heard of ***put down the fire*** being used to mean ***damp down*** or ***control*** a blaze.

Comment: @FumbleFingers [It is in use](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNQh8S3BzvgyhcgGzNkLuD1_HVyWag%3A1575398183266&ei=J6vmXbbmD_Gpgge13YrwBw&q=%22put+down+the+fire%22&oq=%22put+down+the+fire%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i10k1.11389.13196.0.13320.8.7.0.0.0.0.97.492.6.6.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.3.250...33i299k1.0.nghAbohBb1c), but may not be in prevalent use. "She managed to put down the fire twice." "It could literally sit over a crippled airplane and dispense foam to put down the fire before the trucks were able to approach."

Comment: Yeah, I did actually catch sight of that specific example when I searched Google Books for ["**put down the fire**"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22put+down+the+fire%22). But in my experience GB lists many instances where the *exact* quoted text doesn't actually occur, so I routinely switch the default "Sort by Relevance" to "Sort by Date", which usually seems to improve things. But curiously, in this specific case that "definitely present" instance disappears when sorted by date - leaving only ***one*** contextually relevant example (and that apparently from a non-native speaker).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am not sure I understand how "sort by date" is relevant or could make a difference. I cited two attestations both from American authors, and I am able to see them in context on Google Books. Granted the instances are few and far between, but they do make me feel I am not the only person recognizing this usage.

Comment: I've never heard "knock down a fire." Is this British?

Comment: @TypeIA Not unless you consider Spokane/CA/CT British or the US Forest Service a British agency. See [1](https://www.spokesman.com/stories/2019/dec/02/spokane-valley-firefighters-knock-down-duplex-fire/), [2](https://www.actionnewsnow.com/content/fire-watch-stories/Fire-crews-quickly-knock-down-house-fire-in-Chico-565690481.html), [3](https://www.wfsb.com/news/firefighters-knock-down-fire-in-house-during-simsbury-parade/article_88539868-13e7-11ea-b889-379cac7e018d.html), and oh can't forget [US Forest Service](https://www.fs.fed.us/nwacfire/home/terminology.html).

Comment: Learn something new every day! Those are convincing sources, but I'm sure I've never been aware of that expression until now. (Midwest US native speaker FWIW, now expat.)

Comment: So far three people have indicated they haven't heard "put down a fire", one "knock down a fire". I wonder if **people who have heard either** could comment or show some support, just so I can tell the part of me screaming "You serious?" to shut up.

Comment: @EddieKal: My first comment wasn't all *that* "serious" - it didn't accompany a downvote or anything like that. But as [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put+out+the+fire%2Cput+down+the+fire&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cput%20out%20the%20fire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cput%20down%20the%20fire%3B%2Cc0) shows, *put **down** the fire* is incredibly rare compared to the idiomatic standard *put **out** the fire*. And whereas Google books has plenty of *put the fire **out***, I can't read a single instance of *put the fire **down***.

Comment: btw - When I was a child (60-odd years ago), my father would tell me to *knock the fire **down*** and my mother would tell me to *bank the fire **up*** in the evening. But they both meant the same thing (***damp*** the kitchen stove, by raking under the grating, piling fresh coal on top, and pushing the baffle plate in to restrict airflow so the fire would just smoulder gently all night, ready to be opened up again in the morning).

Comment: @FumbleFingers As soon as you raised doubts about "put down a fire", I looked it up on Google Books. Yes the instances are few and far between, and I have realized that from GB and acknowledged it in my comment. To be honest I am surprised "put down the fire" even shows on that NGram, because vanishingly rare usages don't plot on NGrams. But I am still puzzled **why you are not seeing the two instances I cite in a comment.** Those are extracted from real books. I'll happily revise the answer if this discussion convinces me those are false positives, but so far they seem worthy ur consideration

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is not how I understand "knock a fire down", but it makes sense. The definition from the US Forest Service (linked in a comment) points to this. However, in new pieces "knock down a fire" seems to mean the same thing as "put out a fire". I've more often heard "bank the fire" instead of "bank up the fire". Nevertheless, I have always wondered how putting a lot of coal on top is going to make the fire burn more slowly. I thought it would do the opposite and just stoke it up.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Sorry but your NGram evidence doesn't hold water. If anything it helps my argument. Check out [this NGram comparing "is thought of as" and "is thought about as"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+thought+about+as%2Cis+thought+of+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). I have to say "put down the fire" actually fares better in your NGram than "is thought about as" in mine. Is "is thought about as" a real locution? Hundreds of authors seem to say yes (GB link too long). As I said, truly vanishingly rare usages don't plot on NGrams.

Comment: I don't know why "sort by date" affects estimated hits in Google Books, but it definitely does. The initial display from a search for **is thought about as** suggests there are at least 10 pages of results available, but after switching to "sort by date" that drops to just 2 pages. Doing the same on a search for **is thought of as** (which as a native speaker I would know perfectly well is far more common), there are *still* at least 10 pages of results for both sequences. Note that the "about" version isn't actually "incorrect" (in some specific contexts it's actually *preferred*)